# i want to find counters but this code show error

Tags: python, opencv, contour

import cv2

import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mp

image=cv2.imread('D:\instagramphotos\IMG_2012.jpg')

image=cv2.resize(image,(700,500))

imgrey=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(imgrey,200,255,0)

counter,hierarcy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

print("no of counter:", len(counter))

cv2.drawContours(imgrey,thresh,-1,(255,0,0),3)

```
cv2.drawContours(imgrey,thresh,-1,(255,0,0),3)
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2501: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'

Comment: plz answer asap

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use / instead of \ slash when you're reading image